# Sets question on intersection of infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ be sets such that for each $n$ we have $A_1\cap\ldots\cap A_n \ne\varnothing$. Can we have

$$A_1\cap A_2 \cap\ldots = \varnothing\;?$$

This question should be easy as its an earlier one but i feel like im missing something.It seems to me that in both cases if it holds for all $n$ then there's no reason why it shouldn't hold as $n$ goes off to infinity My question is, why would they not be non-empty?

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by A1 ∩ . . . ∩ An 6= ∅? Please edit your post to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: Choose $$A_n = \left(0, \frac 1 n\right) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$$

Then the intersection is nonempty, while each finite intersection is an open interval.

---

For a more direct example, choose

$$A_n = \{n, n + 1, n + 2, ...\} \subseteq\mathbb{N}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can: take $A_n=\left(0,\frac1n\right)$, for instance. Another example is $A_n=\{k\in\Bbb Z^+:k\ge n\}$. In each case $\bigcap_{k=1}^nA_k=A_n\ne\varnothing$, but $\bigcap_{n\ge 1}A_n=\varnothing$.

Of course there are also examples in which the intersection of the entire collection is non-empty. You could, for instance, have $A_n=\left[0,\frac1n\right)$, in which case $\bigcap_{n\ge 1}A_n=\{0\}$.

Comment: @user116498: What new interval?

Comment: Ignore me i was being stupid, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @user116498: You’re welcome.